# How to make certain keystoke in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, script, time

I am trying to make a program that records a live stream for a certain amount of time and then saves it on my desktop. This is what I have so far.

TWiT Live Recorder (30 sec version)

```
tell application "Terminal"
     do script "curl http://bglive-a.bitgravity.com/twit/live/high --ignore-content length -o ~/Desktop/TWiT_Live_Archive.flv"
     delay 30
end tell
tell application "System Events"
     keystroke "^C" (^C is the stop signal)
end tell
```

But for some reason this does not stop the recording. Why do you think this would be and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^C` is not a valid keystroke. Use:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "c" using control down
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I've haven't an OSX up my sleeve but I think the problem is : `^C` is not like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

What you are looking for is :

```
keystroke "c" using control down
```

---

edit: Was too slow :3